# How to access Access json body/content (IActionResult)

Tags: c#, json, azure, rest

I have an endpoint that calls another function that returns json object(IActionResult). How do I access the json data?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
             var empFunc = new employeeFunc(arg);

             var response = await empFunc.GetInfo(req,log);

        return response;

}
```

If I access the end point via postman.

```
{
    "message": "Found 2 records.",
    "entries": [
        {"id": "12345",
         "name":"Tony"
        },
        {"id": "123456",
         "name":"David"
        }
    ]
```

How do I access the json data in my C# code?

I tried something like following

```
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
JObject object = JObject.Parse(readStreamToString(stream));
```

But errored out with following error

```
Error   CS1061  'IActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no accessible extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type 'IActionResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I also tried with

```
dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
```

and errors

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult' to 'string'
```

Comment: How about define a class for output like `MyOutput` and use `var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyOutput>(response);`? Did you try this?

Comment: Try casting the response to `OkObjectResult` and then try to access the data.

Comment: @Tachyon then how to access the data? I tried OkObjectResult newresponse = new OkObjectResult(response);  Tried with both method listed as above and same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpClient` for API call in C# and access to the data:

```
HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("Your API URL");
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Now, you have your JSON in `jsonResult`. You can simply use `Newtonsoft` package to convert it to your own data type.

```
var finalResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyOutput>(jsonResult);

public class Entry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyOutput
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

If you are calling the API directly, then you can use this:

```
var controller = new YourController();
var okResult = await controller.GetInfo(req, log) as OkObjectResult;
var finalResult = okResult.Value as MyOutput;
```

Comment: GetInfo is not a public endpoint. so I have to create instance and call it

Comment: What is its access modifier then?

Comment: Why are you returning IActionResult then? The only purpose of this type is to be serialized to an http response stream in response to an external call. If you need `GetInfo` to return a meaningful type that you can access in C#, just return that type.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "public endpoint"? You've demonstrated that you can call it externally over http using PostMan.

Comment: @SaeidAmini Thanks, I tried with var okResult = await controller.GetInfo(req, log) as OkObjectResult;
var finalResult = okResult.Value as MyOutput; but finalResult is null. Not sure why.  I need debug to see whats going on.